# Django deserialize with one field but serialize with other field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models. Bar is related to Foo via foreign key. In my Bar serializer, I have FooSerializer so it can serializer from its model:

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(source='*')
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

then my Foo Serializer looks like:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('name', 'link')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # Save depending on name
        foo = Foo.objects.get(name=data)
        return {'foo': foo}

    def get_link(self, object):
        print('req', object.id)
        if object.id and request:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(
                '/app/foo/{}'.format(object.id))
        return None
```

I want to able to post in Bar with Foo's `name` field, for example:

```
{
"bar_name": "Nikko",
"foo": "The Foo",
}
```

but the response I want is:

```
{
"bar_name": "Nikko",
"foo": {
      "name": "The Foo",
      "link": "https://localhost:8000/apps/foo/1",
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You need to make one field write-only and another read-only:

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(source='*', read_only=True)
    foo_write = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Foo.objects.all(), write_only=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

I use SlugRelatedField, which will let you use the name attribute to search for a Foo instance. It assumes Name field is unique, otherwise you won't be able to retrieve the right instance.

You might need to add `source="Foo"` on the `SlugRelatedField` if it does not reconize which field it refers to.

Comment: The name in my post would change right? ex. `{
"bar_name": "Nikko",
"foo_write": "The Foo",
}`

Comment: In the POST request, yes. You can not give the same name for two different fields unfortunetely.

Comment: Is there any way to have `foo` and `foo_write` have the same name? I would use `foo` when reading (GET), and `foo_write` when writing (POST) so there shouldn't be ambiguity

Comment: @user1315621 No (they are 2 attributes of the class., so need to have different names), the only case is if you want to return HTML instead of JSON see label argument https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#label.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom response, you have to override `to_represendation(self, instance)`. [drf-doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields)

#### update

If you want to add extra `context` and get information from `request`, you can add it like that

[add extra context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

```
serializer = FooSerializer(..., context={'request': request})
```

Getting data of request, use `self.context` in your `to_representation()`

Comment: How do I pass `request` in to_representation?